# You have exceeded your quota Youtube however I haven't made a single API request in > 24 hours

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have tried to make youtube api requests from Web using this for example
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&q=Ferrari&key=api_key all I get is you have exceeded your quota but this is a new api_key and I haven't made any requests using my account.

Comment: I'm having this same issue right now, very little use over the last 24 hours and only quota errors. I've tired creating a new OAuth Client and API key as well, without success. And it's not my implementation; I get this quota error when using my client ID/secret in the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground). Definitely at my wit's end trying to debug this.

Comment: I just submitted a bug issue report on Google IssueTracker